# Laravel 5+ Como hacer menus dinamicos

Tags: php, laravel, menú

mi pregunta es cómo hacer en laravel menús dinámicos, que deben aparecer en todas las vistas.

El menú debe salir de la tabla categories, y la puedo cachear para que la consulta no se repita veces innecesarias.

[image: Categorias]

Pero como hago para que salga en todas las vistas (especialmente en mi archivo *sidebar.blade.php*)

Si fuera que lo necesito en una sola vista sería sencillo.

Saludos y Gracias

Comment: podrias crear en tu tabla un idPadre para despues recorrerlos en la vista

Comment: Revisa [ask] que te da información para realizar una buena pregunta y de esta forma obtengas buenas respuestas!. Es importante modifiques el formato de tu pregunta agregando lo que has tratado o investigado, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear un archivo `mostrarCategoria.blade.php` o como le quieras llamar y ahi pones la logica para imprimir las categorias despues solo incluyes ese archivo donde necesites mostrar las categorias.

En tu archivo `sidebar.blade.php`

Pondrias la siguiente linea

```
@include('mostrarCategoria.blade.php')
```

Espero te sirva o ayude, saludos